# Axiomatic Quantum Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, mathematical-physics

Is there any practical advantage/disadvantage between using the axioms for the Hilbert Space formulation as opposed to the C* Algebra formulation of Quantum Theory?

If not, then is it possible to establish the equivalence between the two, at least in principle?

Comment: The algebraic formulation takes into account more naturally the existence of inequivalent irreucible representations of CCR/CAR (cf. Haag's theorem in QFT), and more broadly it allows to take into account all relevant quantum states at once. On the other hand, without a concrete Hilbert space formulation it is very difficult to define unbounded operators, and especially the generators of time translations, and thus dynamical systems. The most sensible thing is to choose which formulation to use depending on the context.

Comment: If one is interested only in (isolated) non-relativistic quantum systems then the algebraic formulation is a bit redundant, in my opinion. For quantum field theories and quantum statistical mechanics instead, it is much more relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algebra of (bounded) operators acting on the Hilbert space $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is a $C^{*}$-algebra. Therefore, its subalgebra generated by the observables of a particular quantum mechanical model is itself a $C^{*}$-algebra.

Given a $C^{*}$-algebra and an *algebraic state* $\omega$, one can reconstruct a $*$-representation of the algebra on the Hilbert space via [GNS reconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfand%E2%80%93Naimark%E2%80%93Segal_construction). This gives the Hilbert space formulation for a $C^{*}$-algebraic model, as long as there is an algebraic state. For example, Wightman reconstruction in QFT uses the *vacuum expectation value* as the algebraic state on the $C^{*}$-algebra of polynomials in the quantum field, and its GNS $*$-representation is the Hilbert space of Quantum Field Theory.

Hence, Hilbert space formulations and algebraic formulations are very much related, though not completely equivalent. You need an algebraic state to pass from one to another (and different choices of states can lead to different results). Also, algebraic formulations deal with "nets" of $C^{*}$-algebras as e.g. in Haag-Kastler axiomatics (where there's a separate algebra for each open region of spacetime), not with a single $C^{*}$-algebra, so the algebraic axiomatics is more general from a mathematical point of view.

In quantum mechanics (where there's a finite number of degrees of freedom), the Stone-von-Neumann theorem guarantees that there is only one representation of the Weyl $C^{*}$-algebra, which makes the two formalisms equivalent. The same is not true for QFT.

Comment: A state (infinitely many) on a C*-algebra always exists.

Comment: @yuggib true. But different states lead to inequivalent representations, so you need a physical motivation to choose the correct state

Comment: Not all states lead to inequivalent representations, and there are algebras of observables (e.g. the ones of non-relativistic quantum mechanics) whose (pure) states have all equivalent representations. The distinction is only relevant in QFT.

Comment: @yuggib I never said all states lead to inequivalent representations. (Actually I said different, should have been various)

Comment: You said, I quote, "different states lead to inequivalent representations". I just wanted to point out, for some readers that may be less experienced, that it is not always true.

Comment: @yuggib yeah I meant they can lead to different representations not that they always do so. I think that interpretation is safe but I changed it in my answer

Comment: Just curious, why is the same not true for QFT? Is there no relativistic version of the Stone-von-Neumann theorem?

Comment: @N.Steinle it isn't because of relativity, but because in QFT, we have an infinite number of degrees of freedom. Imagine an infinite number of oscillators, each has its usual energy levels. The set of all possible sequences of non-negative integers then labels a state of the system. It is easy to see that there is an uncountably infinite number of them. Hence, they can't fit in a Hilbert space. In fact, there are an uncountably infinite number of Hilbert space representations in this space. One is generated by creation operators acting on the vacuum (a sequence of zeroes) – the Fock repr.

Comment: @N.Steinle that Stone-von-Neumann doesn't hold for QFT has been known for a while, in fact, an even more striking result known as Haag's theorem is that interacting QFT, though it uses the same $C^{*}$-algebra of observables as the corresponding free QFT, can't use the same (read unitarily equivalent) $*$-representation. Equivalently, the vacuum of interacting QFT is not a state of the free QFT, but belongs to a different representation alltogether.